# Why below EBS deployement failing?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running the this on corretto 8 running on amazon linux 2/2.3.13..
it gets the error as "An error occurred during the execution of command [app-deploy] - [CheckProcFileForJavaApllication]. Stop ruuning the command. Error: There is no profile and .jar file at the root level of your source bundle.

The commands while deployment are prestep

```
cd $WORKSPACE
echo "Downloading the tagged zip file"
/usr/local/bin/s3cmd get s3://prod-bucket/directory/java-app/$tag.zip
mv $tag.zip vet.zip
unzip vet.zip
rm vet.zip
```

Post step command

```
mkdir my_folder;
cp -R .ebextensions my_folder;
cp Procfile.txt my_folder;
cp version.txt my_folder;
cp target/edddpub-parser-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar my_folder;
zip -r my_dir.zip my_folder;
```

**It used to work on Linux1 but i want to run it on Linux2**

***Below is my zip structure:***

```
.ebextensions
     5dantarceDownload
     6danttraceInstallAndPost
     7crowdsrtike_linux2
     nginx_restart_post_hook
.platform
     nginx
         conf.d
             myconf.conf
```

Comment: What is the structure of your zip?

Comment: .ebextensions / nginx / conf.d /myconf.conf

Comment: .ebextensions
     5dantarceDownload
     6danttraceInstallAndPost
     7crowdsrtike_linux2
     nginx_restart_post_hook
.platform
     nginx
         conf.d
             myconf.conf

Comment: So where is your jar as the error msg says it's missing?

Comment: I don't have it! It was working on linux1 but when i switched it to linux2 it doesn't

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71613119/16073570

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`linux2` is vastly different from `linux1` and is **incompatible** with it. Yo may probably need to fully re-design your application to work with `linux2`. Please check AWS docs:

- [Migrating your Elastic Beanstalk Linux application to Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html)

Comment: Now i m getting this https://stackoverflow.com/q/71613119/16073570